# Tricky NullPointerException while sending a file to a client

Tags: java, eclipse, server-side

I am working on a simple server in Java that should have a capability of transferring a file across computers. I am getting a `NullPointerException` on line 77 of Protocol.class. Here is the stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at Protocol.processInput(Protocol.java:77)
       at Server.main(Server.java:41)
```

Why does this happen? There is no `null` references on line 77!

Client.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;


public class Client {

    private static boolean filein = false;
    private static ArrayList<String> fln = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println(
                "Usage: java Client <host name> <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String hostName = args[0];
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try (
            Socket kkSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            BufferedReader stdIn =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fromServer;
            String fromUser = null;

            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("@file")) { filein = true; 
                fromUser = "";}
                else if(fromServer.equals("@end@")) {

                    filein = false;
                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                    int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
                    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                           String fname = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                           File f = new File(fname);
                           f.createNewFile();
                           PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(f);
                           for(int i = 0; i < fln.size(); i++) {

                               p.println(fln.get(i));

                           }

                           p.close();
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File saved!");
                    }


                }
                else if (filein == true) {

                    fln.add(fromServer);
                    System.out.println(fln.get(fln.size() - 1));

                }
                if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                    break;

                if (!filein) fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
                else if (filein) fromUser = "@contintueFileRun";
                if (fromUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                    out.println(fromUser);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Server.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import static java.lang.System.out;

/**
 * Title: FTP Server
 * @author Galen Nare
 * @version 1.0
 */

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        out.println("Starting server!");

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Server <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try ( 
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            String inputLine, outputLine;

            // Initiate conversation with client
            Protocol kkp = new Protocol();
            outputLine = kkp.processInput("");
            out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
                out.println(outputLine);
                if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, Protocol.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Protocol {

    enum ServerState {

        STARTING,
        WAITING

    }  

    ArrayList<String> lns;

    boolean fileout = false;
    int i = 0;

        private ServerState state = ServerState.STARTING;

        public String processInput(String theInput) throws Exception {
            String theOutput = "";

            if (state == ServerState.STARTING) {
                theOutput = "Hello, Client!";
                state = ServerState.WAITING;
            }

            if (!theInput.equals("")) {
                if(theInput.length() > 10 && theInput.startsWith("e")) {
                if (theInput.substring(0,11).equalsIgnoreCase("executecmd ")) {
                theOutput = theInput.substring(11);
                System.out.println(theOutput);
                 try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

                    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(theInput.substring(11));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                theOutput = "Executed " + theInput.substring(11) + ".";
                }
            } else if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {

                theOutput = "Stopping Server!";
                System.exit(0);

            } else if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("executecmd")) {

                theOutput = "Usage: executecmd <command [-options]>";


            } else if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("getfile")) {

                theOutput = "Usage: getfile <file>";

            } else if(theInput.length() > 7 && theInput.startsWith("g")) {
                System.out.println("in");
                if (theInput.substring(0,8).equalsIgnoreCase("getfile ")) {
                theOutput = theInput.substring(8);
                File f = new File(theInput.substring(8));
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
                ArrayList<String> lns = new ArrayList<>();
                while(scan.hasNext()) {
                    lns.add(scan.nextLine());
                }
                for (int i=0; i < lns.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(lns.get(i));
                }
                scan.close();
                lns.add("@end@");
                theOutput = "@file";
                fileout = true;
                }
            } else if (fileout && i < lns.size()) {

                    theOutput = lns.get(i);
                    i++;

            } else if (fileout && i == lns.size()) {

                i = 0;
                fileout = false;

            } else {


                theOutput = "That is not a command!";

            }


            }
            System.out.print(theOutput);
            return theOutput;
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SLaks line 77 is as follows: `} else if (fileout && i < lns.size()) {`

Comment: so... which of those is the only one that can be null, and thus has to be the one being null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never initializing `lns` in `Protocol`, so it's always a `null` reference. You may be able to get away with just changing the declaration to:

```
private List<String> lns = new ArrayList<String>();
```

(I've made it private and changed the type to `List` just out of habit...)

You should also consider giving it a more readable name - is it meant to represent lines? If so, call it `lines`!

(Next, consider why you weren't able to diagnose this yourself. Did you step through this in the debugger? Why did you think there were no null references on line 77? What diagnostic steps did you take in terms of adding extra logging etc? It's important to use errors like this as a learning experience to make future issues more tractable.)

Comment: I did step through this in the debugger. I am not an extremely new Java programmer.